# CLIPS Conflict Resolution Strategies

Tags: expert-system, clips

From what I read there are 7 strategies in CLIPS : Depth, Breadth, Simplicity, Complexity, Random, LEX and MEA.

The ones that i have problems with are LEX an MEA. I have read their description on [1], but I did not quite understood them. An example will also be welcomed.

[1] http://www.comp.rgu.ac.uk/staff/smc/teaching/clips/vol1/vol1-5.3.html

Answer (score 0):

These are strategies used by the OPS5 expert system shell. OPS5 didn't support rule priorities, so these strategies were used to control rule execution using the recency of the facts and in the case of mea the first pattern is given priority. Pretty much the only reason you'd want to use these strategies is to assist in converting an OPS5 program to CLIPS.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict resolution modes are (this matters only between rules with the same salience):

- depth: activations that were activated last are executed first. If multiple rules are activated at the same time then they're executed in arbitrary order (this arbitrary order looks to me like rules defined first are executed first but documentation says "arbitrary" so I wouldn't rely on that).
- breadth: activations activated first are executed first. If multiple activations are activated at the same time then their execution order is arbitrary.
- simplicity: activations with lower "specificity" are executed first. Documentation doesn't say what happens if multiple rules have the same specificity. Rule gets +1 specificity for each comparison (to constant, to a bound variable, comparison operator)
- complexity: activations higher "specificity" are executed first. Documentation doesn't say what happens if multiple rules have the same specificity.
- LEX: activations where sorted list of time-tags of facts matching the activation is later in lexycographic order is activated first (first we compare timestamp of the newest fact matching each activation, activation with newer fact runs first; if they're the same we compare 2nd newest fact on the tied activations and so on...)
- MEA: first we compare time tags of facts matching the first pattern, activation with newer fact runs first. If first fact is the same we run in LEX order. This lets you kind of define your own priorities (first pattern is something like (priority-n) and rules with higher priority run first)